# Why the layout_below is invalid that running on the phone?

Tags: android, android-layout

[This is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpv0c.jpg). My question is that the id is "below_button" `LinearLayout` is invalid that running on the phone. The phone didn’t display this `LinearLayout`, but others layout is right. How come?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/title"
        layout="@layout/toptitlebar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/query_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:background="#e2dfdf"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ram_assistinqnum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:hint="通知书编号"
            android:maxLines="1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ram_operate_date"
            style="@style/SpinnerCtl_Wrap"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:hint="操作时间"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ram_query"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/ram_query"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.sdrcu.operatingdecisions.view.scrollabletbv.ScrollTableView4
        android:id="@+id/scrollTableView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/query_detail"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/below_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#e2dfdf"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollTableView"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ram_arrow_previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:src="@drawable/ram_arrow_previous"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paging"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="翻页"
            android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ram_arrow_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:src="@drawable/ram_arrow_next"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ram_agree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/ram_agree"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ram_disagree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/ram_disagree"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Seal

> In my layout editor's Preview I changed the "Theme in Editor" to "Theme"
>   And I started to get errors like your screenshot.

See:

[image]

So, I selected "All" -> "AppTheme" from the "Theme in Editor" option... Do not forget to press "Ok"

[image]

And the errors went away:

[image]

> So, why do not you also try to set it to "All" -> "AppTheme"

Further it appears to me that you might have created style(s) which do not inherit from "proper parent".

> Using below example: "AppTheme" inherits all the required attributes from "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar". And thus, you need to only specify the attributes you need modified.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    ...

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    ...
</style>
```

Comment: I didn't missing this two attribute. I used the style to quote the layout that SpinnerCtl_Wrap.

Comment: @Seal I just added "screenshot" of how this layout looks on my Android device. Are you seeing the same on your Android device? (Obviously I have commented out com.sdrcu.operatingdecisions.view.scrollabletbv.ScrollTableView4 as I do not have this class)

Comment: Yes, "ScrollTableView4" is my defined class. And how can I do it? Sorry, i am a new Android Developer! Thanks!

Comment: yes, I can seeing the same on my Android device! This shows that the problem is the "ScrollTableV‌​iew4"?

Comment: @Seal Can you attach a screenshot of your layout editor? See my answer I changed the picture to a screenshot of my layout Editor. I just want to see the errors which are being shown on the "Preview" on right side.

Comment: @CaualCoder I have already upload the screenshot. Please check the image link!

Comment: @Seal It is some "style" problem. I have little knowledge in that area. But wait a second. I am changing my answer which might solve your problem.

Comment: @Seal Answer updated. Try to check if it helps you. If there is still problem Can you paste the contents of your "styles"?

Comment: I solved the problem! I confirmed that requirement is "below_button" must be fixed in the bottom of the RelativeLayout. So I used "layout_alignParentBottom" to solved in the "below_button"  LinearLayout.Still thank you for your help!@CasualCoder

Comment: @Seal Ah... I was not even able to find the problem. Thanks for sharing the solution to your problem. And no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
android:layout_below="@id/query_detail"
```

in

```
<com.sdrcu.operatingdecisions.view.scrollabletbv.ScrollTableView4
    android:id="@+id/scrollTableView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/query_detail"
    />
```

with

```
android:layout_below="@+id/query_detail"
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you miss the parameter height and weight

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

add in your layout it works [Use the  Tag](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)